# Azure build Pipeline not adding "Integrated in Build X" link to work item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-boards

The YAML that defines the Azure Pipeline is defined in an Azure Repository.

The actual app code is contained in a GitHub repository (on which the commits referencing work items are made).

The pipeline is configured to link work items automatically [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/configure-pipelines-work-tracking?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#automatically-link-work-items-to-builds-or-releases), using `*` to select all branches.

The Pipeline adds the Github Repository as a resource repositories, checks it out correctly, detects the work item AB#XXX based on Git commit messages, and show the linked work items in the Run summary:

[image]

**However, when opening the listed work item, we don't have any Build link**, only the Git-related links:
[image]

I would expect an "Integrated in Build" linke the following to have been added:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Integrated in Build" link is not supported in your scenario. It only applies with Azure Repo branch.

[image]

To prove this, for Azure pipeline directly using GitHub Repo, "Automatically link work item included in this run" is not shown.

[image]

Comment: Hm I was afraid of that answer. Do you happen to have a link to a documentation that indicate that incompatibility?